# [c++]The importance of dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

I wrote a doubly linked list, and trying to add an `append()`(insert at the end)and `len()`(caculate the number of member in the list). I just don't understand why it doesn't work now. Here is the simplest code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class linkedList{  
private:  
    struct node{  
        node* last;
        node* next;  
        char* str;  
    };  
    node sentinel;  
public:  
    linkedList();  
    ~linkedList();  
    int len();  
    void append(char*);  
};  

linkedList::linkedList(){  
    sentinel.last=&sentinel;  
    sentinel.next=&sentinel;  
    sentinel.str="I am sentinel!!";  
};  

linkedList::~linkedList(){};  

int linkedList::len(){  
    node* currentNode=&sentinel;  
    int count=0;  
    while ((*currentNode).next!=&sentinel){  
        count++;  
        currentNode=(*currentNode).next;  
        cout<<(*currentNode).str<<endl;  
    }  
    return count;  
}  

void linkedList::append(char* str){  
    node newNode;  
    newNode.str=str;  
    newNode.last=sentinel.last;  
    (*sentinel.last).next=&newNode;  
    sentinel.last=&newNode;  
    newNode.next=&sentinel;  
}  

int main(){  
    linkedList myList;  
    myList.append("Hello");  
    myList.append("World");  
    int length=myList.len();  
    cout<<length<<endl;  
    return 0;  
}
```

What I am doing is just add two new nodes into the linked list, and caculate the total number of my nodes. it should return 2. but why it doesn't work?

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: _"just don't understand why it doesn't work"_ is pretty vague. Exactly how does it not work?

Comment: Use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)...Life is too short to reinvent it.

Comment: exe broke when I run it.

Comment: `node newNode;` You need to use pointers and allocate them dynamically.

Comment: why infinite loop? I always link the last node back to the sentinel.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am a student, just do some excecise in Christmas vacation :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*newNode* in your code below will go out of scope as soon as append is finished executing. Assigning it's memory address as a pointer to more global member is likely going to end in a segfault.

```
void linkedList::append(char* str){  
    node newNode;  
    newNode.str=str;  
    newNode.last=sentinel.last;  
    (*sentinel.last).next=&newNode;  
    sentinel.last=&newNode;  
    newNode.next=&sentinel;  
}
```

Try allocating your node on the heap using `new node`, possibly using a shared_ptr to make memory management a bit simpler.

```
void linkedList::append(char* str){  
    node *newNode = new node;  
    newNode->str=str;  
    newNode->last=sentinel.last;  
    (*sentinel.last).next=newNode;  
    sentinel.last=newNode;  
    newNode->next=&sentinel;  
}
```

With this approach, be sure to cleanup the nodes when destructing your linkedlist, via the `delete` operator on each node.

Alternatively, look into using [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)'s to a Node instead of raw pointers, which will always call `delete` when the linkedlist (and nobody else) is pointing to the node.

Comment: you mean I should use `node* newNode=new node();`? I ll have a try.

Comment: thx guy! I understand the problem now!

Comment: another question, how to delete those nodes added by `append()` when the program is finish?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `new` keyword to allocate a new node on the heap:

```
void linkedList::append(char* str){  
    node *newNode = new node();  
    newNode->str=str;  
    newNode->last=sentinel.last;  
    (*sentinel.last).next=newNode;  
    sentinel.last=newNode;  
    newNode->next=&sentinel;  
}
```